# Why can't I insert a row at index 0 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table with an `id` column as the primary key (int). When I run this statement, it creates a new row, but with an auto incremented `id` value:

```
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`id`,`id_user`,`someString`) VALUES (0, 0, 'Hello World')
```

Produces:

```
id (pk) | id_user | someString
1       | 0       | Hello World
2       | 0       | Hello World
3       | 0       | Hello World
```

Why does this happen? Shouldn't I be able to have an index of 0?

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried this but i suspect you can
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html if "No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly assign 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers, unless the NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO SQL mode is enabled"
If you do specify a value then mysql will accept it (as long as it does not cause a primary key error) and subsequent inserts will increment as normal where you do not specify it. So it is entirely possibly that you could create discontinuities should you wish to do so.

For example

```
ariaDB [sandbox]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> CREATE TABLE T (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, VAL VARCHAR(3));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO T (ID,VAL) VALUES (3,'AAA');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO T (ID,VAL) VALUES (2,'CCC');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO T (ID,VAL) VALUES(1,'BBB');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO T (VAL) VALUES ('DDD');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO T (ID,VAL) VALUES (10,'EEE');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> INSERT INTO T (VAL) VALUES ('FFF');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM T;
+----+------+
| ID | VAL  |
+----+------+
|  1 | BBB  |
|  2 | CCC  |
|  3 | AAA  |
|  4 | DDD  |
| 10 | EEE  |
| 11 | FFF  |
+----+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever try to write to an auto-increment field. MySql indexes always start with 1. If you have some operational need for an index of 0, you'll have to create your own index with each new record.

Comment: So what is happening when I ask to insert/update an index of 0? Why does it create a new row instead of giving me an error?

Comment: I think it ignores the value you're trying to insert and just assigns a new row.